# How to ignore file until next modification or temprorarily?

Tags: git, version-control

I have cloned repository and there is database.php file where credentials are different and every time I need commit and push, I have to add every file manually except database file, then push. Like:

```
git add file_name
git add another_file_name
.....
git push origin
```

Is there a way to ignore database.php file for all the commits I do, except when database.php is again modified for server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From "[Git - Difference Between 'assume-unchanged' and 'skip-worktree'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23806990/6309)", use [`git update-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index):

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged -- database.php
```

Any local change will be ignored by `git status`.
The next `git pull` will restore the remote content in the local repo.

To stop ignoring local change at any time:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged -- database.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `database.php` into `.gitignore` and clear it's `cache` by running `git rm --cache .gitignore`.

P.S : This file will always be ignore untill you remove it from `.gitignore` and clear the `cache`.

Comment: I want to ignore for temporarily

Comment: start ignoring changes to a file:
--------------------------------------------
git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/file
keep tracking again:
--------------------------------------------
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged path/to/file

Answer (score 0):

**Try This one:**

Remove it from the project directory (without actually deleting it): git rm --cached database.php

If you don't already have a .gitignore, you can make one right inside of your project folder: project/.gitignore.

Put database.php in the .gitignore

Stage the file to commit: git add project/.gitignore

Commit: git commit -m "message".

Push your change to git.